# Does there exist a method call to get unaccepted answers?

Tags: feature-request, api

I noticed there was the method `/questions/unanswered` which returns questions with no upvoted answers but I'm more interested in something like `/questions/unaccepted` which returns all questions that have no accepted answers.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a specific route that does this, but you could call one of the question routes and then check to see if each of them has an accepted answer.